# Using cookies instead of sessions to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgeries

Tags: php, session, cookies

I need to add CSRF protection to an existing site and I'm referring to http://phpmaster.com/preventing-cross-site-request-forgeries/ as a guide on how to prevent CSRF.

In the link, it is suggested that we use $_SESSION as a way of storing the token. I'd like to know if using $_COOKIE is just as safe. Are there any drawbacks of using $_COOKIE over $_SESSION?

**EDIT**: Any idea if using a $_COOKIE instead of $_SESSION is PCI Compliant?

Comment: I always store the session cookie (encrypted) in the db also to compare with, I believe that enhances security... For your question http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/1/0

Comment: Oops, deleted my comment accidentally... Again: You need to make sure that the user's browser has cookies enabled. Otherwise, he won't be able to submit any form. Also, cookie encryption is a good keyword. Otherwise one might be able to inject a CSRF cookie and manipulate your CSRF check.

Answer (score 0):

In the vast majority of cases the PHP session identifiers are transferred through cookies as well (session cookies).

If this is also true for your site -- which it almost certainly is -- then consider what happens if an attacker gains access to your cookies (e.g. through XSS): they don't have any need for CSRF because they can simply hijack the session and enter through the front door. Conclusion: there is no additional security risk if you store the CSRF token in a cookie.

A minor drawback for using an additional CSRF cookie is that it will increase the volume of incoming HTTP traffic by a tiny bit, but that's really just a theoretical difference.

Comment: My site setup is such that using sessions is not an option. We have the site set up on a distributed system.

Comment: @GauravSharma: If you are not using sessions then how does CSRF apply? In effect *every* user request would look (to you) as if it comes from a brand new user. So the only type of user would be "anonymous".

Comment: We are using client-side cookies to maintain a users log in

Comment: @GauravSharma: So if someone can see your cookies they can hijack your users' sessions. As I wrote above, in that case why would they bother with the CSRF token?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying the because I'm using only cookies to store any session data, I should not worry about CSRF and should not add any checks to prevent it?

Comment: @GauravSharma: No, I 'm saying that if someone can circumvert your protection by messing with your CSRF cookie then they can also hijack your sessions, which is far worse. So don't worry about CSRF cookie security any more than you worry about session cookie security.